# Laravel 4 - populate form select multiple with pivot table

Tags: database, forms, select, laravel-4, pivot-table

I'm trying to populate a 'Edit form' with data I should obtain from a pivot table.

I'm editing something called 'Actividad'. And 'Actividad' has some 'Materials'. The 'create'(Actividad) form works correctly, but I can't deal with my 'edit' form...

My Edit form:

```
{{ Form::label('material_id', 'Material necesario:') }}
{{ Form::select('material_id[]', $material_id, Input::old('material_select'), array('multiple')) }}
```

In my Controller I have this:

```
$material_id = DB::table('materials')->orderBy('nombre', 'asc')->lists('nombre', 'id');
```

With this, I have every 'materials' stored in my DB. But I think I need some code to pass to my form a variable with only the materials related to this 'Actividad'...

Any idea about how to obtain these data and how to use it in my form?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `belongsToMany` you need to load the related collection and call `lists` on it:

```
// assuming relation materials on Actividad model:
$actividad->materials->lists('nombre','id');
```

For `hasMany` relation you could do:

```
$model->relation()->lists('name','id');
```

The latter would save you loading the collection of models, but unfortunately there is no way to make it work with pivot table currently.

---

In fact you want to get only data for selected options, right?

Then:

```
$selected = $actividad->materials->lists('id');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It works perfect. But how can I do to show the selected options as chosen? I want to show all the options, but with the options already selected like chosen... I don't know if I'm clear enough... :S

Comment: pass `$selected` array as 3rd param of `Form::select`